# Make string in python behave like a list of one item

Tags: python, string, list

I have a validate function which checks the members of a list returned from another function against a control list of permitted values. This works fine except in the case where the returned list contains a single string. Python then interprets that string as a list of characters. Can I make it process it as though it were a list with only one item? Here is the function:

```
def validate(returned_list, control_list):
    for y in range(len(returned_list)):
       tf = False
       for x in range(len(control_list)):
           if returned_list[y] == control_list[x]:
               tf = True
               break
       if tf == False:
           return returned_list[y]
    return "OK"
```

Comment: See my answer for a solution. Beyond that though, there is a *lot* for this method to be wanting: don't use return-strings to indicated the status - because what happens, if OK is the string that makes you fail? Instead, use a value *not* part of the domain of the function, e.g. None. You should also not use range here, instead, just iterate over the sequences, and compare the elements. Last but not least, boolean tests are not done with ==, but directly: "if not tf", or "if tf".

Comment: I appreciate that. Sorry for subjecting you to the horrors of my inelegant newbie code :)

Comment: And you could also learn the beautiful for-else to avoid the `tf` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for the type here. Like this:

```
 def polymorphic(arg):
     if isinstance(arg, basestring):
         arg = [arg]
     for item in arg:
         print item
```

This is IMHO one of the few instances where you should perform a check like this. Normally, this is discouraged for good reasons, as you'd end up strong-arming Python into something it isn't - a statically typed language. However, the iteration-behaviour of strings makes it necessary every now and then.

Comment: Glad to be of help, if you mark the answer that helped you most as "solved", that would be great :) It might not be mine, but then somebody else is happy to get the karma.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
def validate(returned_list, control_list):
    returned_list = returned_list if isinstance(returned_list, list) else [returned_list]
    for y in range(len(returned_list)):
       tf = False
       for x in range(len(control_list)):
           if returned_list[y] == control_list[x]:
               tf = True
               break
       if tf == False:
           return returned_list[y]
    return "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the comments, here is the revised function:

```
def validate(returned_list, control_list):
    if isinstance(returned_list, basestring):
        returned_list = [returned_list]
    for x in returned_list:
        for y in control_list:
            if x == y:
                break:
        else:
            return x
    return None
```